# Need a script to emulate <cr> pressing in insert mode

Tags: vim

I'm writing a function that automatically inserts some text under certain conditions. I stuck at a part when I try to emulate Enter press. I come up with this (obvious) code:

```
execute "normal! a\<cr>"
```

The problem is that it breaks the autoindentation. For example, I have a text file like this (| is a cursor):

```
if (condition) {
    action();|
```

So I run `execute "normal! a\<cr>"`. When i need this:

```
if (condition) {
    action();
    |
```

it acts like this:

```
if (condition) {
    action();
|
```

Of course, autoindent is on. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually working as expected. If you execute `:execute "normal! a\<cr>hello` it will put 'hello' in the right place. If you press <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> it will drop to the start of the line. The command drops out of insert mode and since it's a blank line, unindents.

Comment: Many thanks. By the way (off-topic), is there any way to actually insert tabs when creating a new line with autoindent on? This sometimes makes me crazy when I exit insert mode on a newly created line and then have to type all the tabs back manually.

Comment: @Susei you could insert a character, escape, then do `x`. For example, `:exe "norm! a\<cr>h\<esc>x"`